# random app crashing with ngRoute

Tags: angularjs

I was following the guides on the AngularJS ngView page, but customizing it to my specific app. When I try to change views, the app crashes.

The relevant code is below:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/items.html',
        controller: 'itemListController',
        controllerAs: 'list'
    }).when('/Item/:itemID', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/item.html',
        controller: 'itemController',
        controllerAs: 'item'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

The items view works just fine when the page loads. However, when I change `$location.path` to `/Item/1`, the app crashes the browser. If I change the `templateUrl` to the same `/templates/items.html` it changes properly, but it obviously doesn't work right as the template is not set up for that controller.

Currently, my `item.html` temnplate is an empty file. I've tried adding things to it with no luck. Likewise, my `itemController` is an empty controller. However, when I inject the `$routeParams` dependency, I get an infinite loop and the "Maximum call stack size limit exceeded" error. Below is my infinite looping controller:

```
app.controller('itemController', ['itemService', '$routeParams', function(itemService, $routeParams){
    console.log($routeParams);
}]);
```

I had a similar problem with my default `/` view, but somehow got it working. After a few hours I have been unable to resolve this problem. Is there something I've done incorrectly? Or is the problem somewhere deeper in my code?

**Update**
As requested in the comments, the controller where I change `$location.path` is my main "view" controller:

```
app.controller('viewController', ['$route', '$routeParams', '$location', function($route, $routeParams, $location){
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.title = "App Name";
    ctrl.$route = $route;
    ctrl.$location = $location;
    ctrl.$routeParams = $routeParams;

    ctrl.changeView = function(view){
        $location.path(view);
    };
}]);
```

`changeView()` is then called inside of elements' `ng-click`. For example, one of the items in `items.html` has `ng-click="view.changeView('/Item/'+item.Id)"`

Comment: what is error that you are getting in the console?

Comment: @sinu There is no error. I get the Chrome "Aw, Snap! something went wrong while displaying this webpage." crash. It seems to work alright in IE, and can't test it in FireFox at the moment.

Comment: Possibly related; seeing as you have HTML5 mode enabled, you have server-side URL rewriting set up. I'd check the browsers *Network* console and make sure the HTML template requests are returning the correct data and not being accidentally rewritten.

Comment: I also assume you have a `<base>` tag setup correctly in your main HTML file.

Comment: @Phil The network calls are to the appropriate files. Though I do see a 404 for the angular.js files (even though higher up in the stack, the same files are loaded correctly...) I am running this app out of a sub folder of my domain (domain.com/test) and have `<base href="/test/">` in my app's `head`

Comment: can you share the controller code in which you change the $location.path ?

Comment: @manasisakhare Updated my question. The name of the controller is not necessarily semantically correct, originally my views were going to be hiding and showing elements via this main controller, instead of actual views.

Comment: Ok. Now I can see that the route configured is "/Item/:itemID" this is always case sensitive. And in the call to changeView() the path has "items" instead of "Item"

Comment: @manasisakhare That is my error. I updated the question again, I wrote it from memory, and not actually copied from the file.

Comment: on ng-click what is the "view" in "view.changeView()"? If you have a viewController assigned to the html view, then you need not do a "view."

Comment: The root controller of my app is `ng-controller="viewController as view"`, which is the same controller that updates `$location.path` with that function. It is named that way from my previous set up. It would be better renamed to 'mainController'